# How to pack linked files from referenced NuGet packages

Tags: json, .net, nuget, nuget-package, pack

I have a build-properties-defining package that is to be used by all the libraries.
Some libraries may provide a json file, that should be retained when they're referenced by some other libraries and then, ultimately, all the configuration files should be transitively provided to a consumer of a top-level library.

There's a convention, that libraries place their configuration files into an `appsettings/cfgs` directory.

Currently I have the following in my build-defining package's `xxx.targets` file

```xml
...
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\appsettings\cfgs\*.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\appsettings\cfgs</PackagePath>
    <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
...
```

What works when using the target file above:

- when a json file is added to `appsettings/cfgs`, it is copied to build output by default
- when a json file is added to library's `appsettings/cfgs`, it is packed into library's NuGet package via `dotnet pack`
- when a library is referenced, its' configuration files are shown in solution explorer as `appsettings/cfgs` linked directory and linked files are copied to consumer's output.

What doesn't work:
I have library1, that provides a configuration file `1.json`. I have library2, that consumes library1's NuGet package:

- `1.json` is shown in solution explorer
- `1.json` is copied to library2's output on build
- `1.json` is NOT, despite my best efforts, included into library2's NuGet package, while library2's json files, lying in the same very directory of output, are successfully packed.

How do I ensure that files, linked from referenced NuGet package, are added to consuming library's NuGet package, produced by `dotnet pack`?

provided by libraries, are  packed into a NuGet package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find a complete answer for my case, I'll provide a solution that works for me so far.

My `xxx.targets` looks like this now

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(ProjectDir)\appsettings\**\*.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <!-- Target below will ensure that the configuration files are correctly packed -->
    <Pack>false</Pack>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="PackConfigurationFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(IsPackable)' == 'true'">
    <Content Include="$(TargetDir)appsettings/cfgs/*.json">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\appsettings\cfgs</PackagePath>
      <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

So, instead of relying on `dotnet pack` to pick up linked files (which it doesn't so far), we're specifically using `appsettings/cfgs` directory in build output, where all our linked configuration files are in fact present along with consumner's own json files, if any.